# APEX: access profile by name in known/predictable language regardless of running user's language

Tags: apex, profile, fields, translation

It was recently brought to my attention that for our clients, SalesForce translates profile names (such as "System Administrator") which causes errors when the Apex code attempts to check profile names in conditional code.

I should have thought translation should only have effected the presentation layer and Apex developers would need to go out of their way to consider it.  But I'm informed this is not the case.

Is there a way I can tell my Apex code that I am only considered with the value stored in a field (e.g. profile.name) and don't care at all whether it has been translated or what it may have been translated to?

Comment: to avoid such issues, you can try using custom settings...

Comment: @baskaran, but then we need to make sure the values are loaded into the custom settings for the unit tests, which aside from being an additional hassle slow them down even further.

Comment: Nice question!! Can you detect the permission you need as opposed to the profile? Kinda analagous to "feature detection" vs "browser detection" in the webdev world? Or limit your interrogation to profiles you explicitly create, which will not be translated?

Answer (score 6):

Profile names can change, but profile ID's don't. I recommend you use the ID instead of the name for that very reason.

Its not unusual with various licenses for someone to clone and rename them. I've encountered this especially with portal user licenses. *Regardless of how they rename it* when that happens, *the license ID still doesn't change*. The same applies to other profile names and ID's.

For that reason, I've learned to only query using the ID instead of the name in my coding.

**Edit**

If you're uncomfortable both with using ID's and with Custom Settings, the only other solution would seem to obtain the translations and add those to your query as part of a logical `OR` statement in your `WHERE` clauses. Either that, or add them via some other means that determines which query to run based on the language environment.

Comment: Won't the ID be different in different sandboxes? So maybe it would work in dev but not prod?

Comment: Not in my experience when it comes to User profiles. Licenses are the same whether you're in a sandbox or in a production org. In cases where an ID of some kind is different, just as with anything else, you can always put in a conditional to test for sandbox vs production. That's easy enough to determine in most situations.

Comment: Generally I'd downvote an answer suggesting you hardcode IDs, but with profiles it's a pretty rough situation. They don't have a "developer name" that's consistent like most other types of metadata SObjects, so depending on your environment hardcoding the id might actually be easiest.

Comment: Generally speaking, I agree. Profiles ID's are usually the only ID's that I hardcode. I've been bitten with profile names changing on me.

Comment: Still I'd go for the custom settings solution. E.g. in case you create a new custom profile, the Id's will not match between environments. I am sure you will not notice a delay in test class performance.

Comment: @crmprogdev, I don't want to use the Ids because I don't want to hardcode them as this may (will) change between environments.  And I don't want to use custom settings because there IS a noticeable performance degradation if/when the unit tests create the custom settings that the class relies on.

Comment: In the same org, licenses don't change, so the ID's won't change for a full-fledged Admin (all other Admins are simply permutations). That being said, see my edited reply. Best of luck to you. :)

Comment: I don't see why test execution time would be used a reason to avoid using a solution. Your test methods are not fired every time a user touches the system, so it isn't going to impact that. You are not likely doing a deploy ever couple minutes, so you won't be noticeably adding time there. If you use a factory class in your tests, you can have a `static` set or map that is populated as you request profiles, and referenced before retrieving profiles.

Comment: What if we need to create a package and deliver to multiple clients, all clients will have different profile id's on their org. In that case it is not feasible to hardcode id's in query and i don't like custom setting approach because it requires manual effort to create custom setting on each client's org.

Comment: Most ISV's these days try to use permission sets for their packages. I would suggest you approach it in that manner. You can then make certain the test user has the permission set needed to run your package. I'd expect that to be language agnostic.